# Open a 2nd Modal and then close the 1st modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have two [Modals](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) and the problem I'm having is with closing the 1st modal after 2nd modal has been opened.

I have tried this. But then it never opens the 2nd Modal.

This is within the 1st Modal

```
async next(): Promise<void> { // try to open 2nd Modal and after that close the 1st Modal
  await this.showSeeAgainModal();
  this.cancel();
}

cancel(): void {
  this.modalController.dismiss();
}

async showSeeAgainModal(): Promise<void> { // This is the 2nd Modal
  const modal: HTMLIonModalElement = await this.modalController.create({
    component: SeeAgainPage,
  });

  modal.onDidDismiss().then(async (res) => {
  });

  return await modal.present();
}
```

**Update:** I have tried with 2 `ModalControllers`. i.e. one for the parent and other for a child. But that too didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `this.modalController.dismiss()`, which closes the active second modal. You need to have a reference to your first modal if you want to dismiss it from the second one. Pass a `dismissFirstModal` function as a `componentProp` to the second modal and take advantage of the [`ionModalDidPresent`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#events) event, which is emitted after the modal has presented.
Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-ahznbn?file=src/app/pages/action-sheet/action-sheet.component.ts)

*first.component.ts*

```
constructor(public modalController: ModalController){}

async presentFirstModal() {
  const dismissFirstModal = () => {
    modal.dismiss();
  };
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: SecondComponent,
    componentProps: {dismissFirstModal: dismissFirstModal}
  });
  return await modal.present();
}
```

*second.component.ts*

```
@Input() dismissFirstModal;

constructor(public modalController: ModalController){}
ngOnInit() {}

async showSeeAgainModal(): Promise<void> {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: SeeAgainPage,
  });

  modal.addEventListener('ionModalDidPresent', () => {
    this.dismissFirstModal()
  })

  return modal.present();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have done this in a different way. i.e. I have around 4 Modals popup workflow. So I didn't close the previous one after opening the 2nd modal since the user was able to come to the previous modal using cancel button on the 2nd modal. But when the user pressed the Submit button it must be closed all the Modals at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `id` when creating a new modal element. For example

```
showSeeAgain(id: string) {
  this.modalCtrl.create(
  {
    component: CreateBookingComponent,
    id: id // here is the id of a new modal
  }).then(
   modalElement => {
      modalElement.present();
      return modalElement.onDidDismiss();
    }).then(data => console.log(data));          
}

cancel(id: string) {
  this.modalCtrl.dismiss({message: 'I am closing a modal'}, 'confirm', id);
}
```

and then you can close a modal when dismissing by using id.

Comment: This is not clear. Can you give me an example according to my use case?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I am not familiar with JavaScript `await` and `async` keywords, but my idea is simple: control when closing and opening a modal using an identifier.